# Add order by to Union Select ALL

Tags: sql

I am using the following query to create an ssrs parameter and need to order by lastname

```
SELECT  Lastname + ', ' + FirstName + ' ' + '(' + INPN + ')' as Agent

FROM tblagents where agentcode in (SELECT AgentCode from AgentDetail)

UNION
SELECT ' ALL'  AS Agent
```

I attempted first to use order by prior to the union.

Then i tried to wrap this all in a select * from

```
SELECT  *
from (
    (SELECT Lastname, Firstname, INPN FROM tblAgents where agentcode in (SELECT AgentCode from AgentDetail) )
    UNION SELECT ' ALL' AS Agent
)
```

that did not work either. 
How can i order by last name in my query?

Comment: What you mean didnt work? I dont see any `order by`  there? What result you expect?

Comment: Tab your question with the database you are using.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza yup, sorry i should have included the complete statement. Whoops

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sintaxis is  `order by` at the end. Not before the union

```
SELECT * FROM Table1
UNION 
SELECT * FROM Table2
ORDER BY <somefield>
```

In your case something like this:

```
SELECT Lastname as OrderField, 
       Lastname + ', ' + FirstName + ' ' + '(' + INPN + ')' as Agent

FROM tblagents 
WHERE agentcode in (SELECT AgentCode FROM AgentDetail)

UNION ALL 

SELECT 'AAAAA' as OrderField,
        'ALL'  AS Agent 
ORDER BY OrderField
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T.Lastname, T.Firstname, T.INPN , T.Agent 
FROM (
        SELECT Lastname, Firstname, INPN , null as Agent
        FROM tblAgents 
        WEHRE agentcode in (SELECT AgentCode 
                            from AgentDetail)
        UNION 
        SELECT null,null,null, 'ALL' AS Agent
      ) AS T
ORDER BY T.Lastname asc
```

Comment: I like this answer as well but i selected the other as it was closer to my application. Thank you for the response.